Hisense A9 on T-mobile network asks for "password" when making phone calls, not sending sms
Simm works fine on previous moto-e phone, also on 4g LTE T-mobile network.  Any help would be appreciated, I have no idea how to even diagnose this.

A screenshot of the password dialog would be helpful.

It's just like a regular phone call, but there's a voice on the other side asking for a password.  Does t-mobile ask for password when changing device or something?  I have no record of ever setting up such a password.

I don't think this is something from Android. Try contacting T-Mobile about this?

Thank you for the tips.

Seems was due to "voicemail" password.  I had to reset it and now it makes phone calls.
